# Hive query fails when I use a view with struct inside an array

Tags: arrays, struct, view, hive

I have a table with an array of struct:

```
CREATE TABLE test1(
  key_value array<struct<
    key:string, string_value:string
  >>
 );
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test1
SELECT array(
   named_struct('key','key0', 'string_value','some string 0'),
   named_struct('key','key1', 'string_value','some string 1'),
   named_struct('key','key2', 'string_value','some string 2'),
   named_struct('key','key3', 'string_value','some string 3')
);
```

Then I created a view against that table with an access directly to the "key" element of struct in the second element in array (don't ask why I need this:)

```
CREATE VIEW v_test1 AS
SELECT 
  key_value[2].key
FROM test1;
```

And when I query that view I get an error:

```
hive> SELECT * from v_test1;
FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 . Operator is only supported on struct or list of struct types 'key' in definition of VIEW v_test1 [
SELECT
  null.`key`
FROM `default`.`test1`
] used as v_test1 at Line 1:14
```

As you can see, for some reason expression **key_value[2].key** was converted into **null.`key`**

Why does it happen and how can I fix that?
Many thanks!

**UPD:**

```
$ hive --version
Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.7.2
```

Comment: same exact issue for me in 1.2.1000

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12785 looks like a similar, if not the same issue with a UNIONTYPE instead of ARRAY. I'm curious if the ARRAY issue is solved in 2.0 as well?

Answer (score 0):

When copying and pasting your code, the `insert overwrite` statement did not compile for me.

I ran:

```
create table test1 as
SELECT array(
  named_struct('key','key0', 'string_value','some string 0'),
  named_struct('key','key1', 'string_value','some string 1'),
  named_struct('key','key2', 'string_value','some string 2'),
  named_struct('key','key3', 'string_value','some string 3')
) as key_value;
```

And the `select * from v_test1` worked as expected (got `key2`).

When I populated the table with a shorter array - I got `NULL`.

I'm using hive version 1.2.1

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your experiment, it seems, we have differrent versions of Hive, my is 1.1.0-cdh-5.7.2
Probably, it is kind of bug, investigating...